# R: Automatically expand margins in VIM::aggr plots

Tags: r

I'm trying to visualise missing data with the R package VIM.
I'm using R version 3.4.0 with RStudio

I've used the function aggr() but the colnames of my dataframe seem to be too long. Thus, some labels of the x axis don't appear.
I would like to increase the space at the bottom of the x axis.

```
library(VIM)
aggr(df)
```

Here is my dataframe df and the plot I obtain
[image: Here is my dataframe df and the plot I obtain]

I've tried with par() function but it doesn't change anything.

```
aggr(df,mar=c(10,5,5,3))
```

or

```
par(mar=c(10,5,5,3))
g=aggr(df,plot=FALSE)
plot(g)
```

I can reduce the font size with cex.axis but then labels are too small.

```
aggr(df,cex.axis=.7)
```

Here is the plot with small axis labels:
[image: Here is the plot with small axis labels]

I've not find a lot of examples using aggr() that's why I ask for your help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for a graphical parameter `oma` which will allow you to resize the main plot. The help reference states:

> For `plot.aggr`, further graphical parameters to be passed down. `par("oma")` will be set appropriately unless supplied (see `par`).

In your case you could do something like:

```
aggr(df, prop = T, numbers = F, combined = F,
 labels = names(df), cex.axis = .9, oma = c(10,5,5,3))
```

Obviously, you need to play around with `cex.axis` and other parameters to find out what works best for your data.

Comment: Thanks, and for all, note, parameters must be set in the aggr() call. They will otherwise be ignored.